# ajax click button run form in background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay, so I have an iput and a button that when I click I want ajax to run a script in the background and update another div with the script in the php file.

Here's the button and input

```
<button type="button" id="calculate" onclick="jQuery('#modal-2').modal('show');"   class="btn btn-purple btn-icon">
<span>calculate</span>
<i class="fa-money"></i>
```

Ajax in the same file:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('calculate').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/system/calculate.php',
        data: 'ammount=' + $('ammount').val() ,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#modal-body').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

and php file running in the background

```
<?php
//edit, do not leave like this.
$ammount = $_POST['ammount'];
$btcvalue = $_POST['price'];
 $total = ($btcvalue * $ammount) * (1 - $system->fee());
echo $fee;
echo 'kjhgjkj';

 ?>



<div class="modal fade custom-width" id="modal-2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 60%;">
    <br/><Br/><br/><Br/>            <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $lang['totalpriceof']; ?> <?=$coin;?> to buy</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">


            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added an alert to the php file calculate and it's not alerting, I've not a clue of the ajax function is working.

debbugged

```
Remote Address:[::1]:80
```

Request URL:system/calculate.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:localhost
Origin:
Referer:/dashboard?ammount=1&price=366.61
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:236
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 08 Dec 2014 18:45:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.19
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering

Preserve log

**Notice**:  Undefined index: ammount in **C:\xampp\htdocs\system\calculate.php** on line **3**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: price in **C:\xampp\htdocs\system\calculate.php** on line **4**
0

Comment: Try ... `$('#calculate').click(function(){` since you are asking for the id

Comment: YEeeesssss! So what is your question?

Comment: This is a semantic error (incorrectly formed code) not sure why it has been upvoted as a question. You should be using a debugger.

Comment: It's just a typo. It's not clear how much the debugger will help.

Comment: This wont work either `data: 'data: 'ammount=' + $('ammount').val()' but you dont show a tag with anything like an id or class or `ammount` so not sure what it should be

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control text-center no-left-border" name="ammount" value="0">

Comment: @jeromeudee To get that value it should be `$("input[name=ammount]").val()`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working nowthing's showing in my model div, it's just blank:

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#calculate').click(function(){
```

...since you are asking for the `id`.

Comment: Thanks @admdrew for the fix ... put this into the comments and should pay more attention once I realize it's the right answer.

Comment: I've added alert("Hello"); to the php file and it's not alerting which is leading me to believe it's not working, I guess.

Comment: Are there any clues in the Inspector; any errors showing?

Comment: Not that I can see. I tried the alert on the ajax success and that work, it just doesn't seem to pull anything from the calculate file

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array as the response.

PHP :

```
$total = ($_POST['price'] * $_POST['ammount']) * (1 - $system->fee());
define('ARRAYSPLIITER', '::');

echo $fee . ARRAYSPLIITER . 'Second String';
```

jQuery Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/system/calculate.php',
     data: 'ammount=' + $('ammount').val() ,
     success: function(msg) {
         array = msg.split("::");
         $('#modal-body').html(array[0]);
         $('#element2').html(array[1]);
     }
})
```